# VMware esxi client for linux?

Tags: esxi

is there a way to connect to VMware esxi 5.1 from a Linux machine?

A sphere client version for Linux?

I have looked for every where I couldn’t find any answers.

Comment: See "Availability of vSphere Client for Linux systems" at kb.vmware.com: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006095

Comment: You can perform most tasks from the CLI (if you enable SSH), except access to VM consoles (virtual keyboard/display).

Comment: There is nothing about linux vsphere client on that site.

Comment: i want to manage machines in gui.  anyone knows somthing please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no vSphere Client for Linux , but there is a workaround for this.  Instead of connecting your vSphere client directly to vCenter, instead, you can connect your vSphere Web Client (Linux version) to your vCenter server and administer your ESX environment that way!

Many of the same features are available through the web client, but not quite all.

Here is the [VMware documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vcenterhost.doc%2FGUID-CE128B59-E236-45FF-9976-D134DADC8178.html) on how to connect to vCenter using the vSphere Web Client in ESX 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

vEMan (VMware ESX(i) Manager) is a tool which helps you manage ESX servers natively from within your Linux desktop without the need to use a Windows VM with vSphere!

It is based on the VMware CLI/SDK and/or other free great user-scripts but using a GUI on top.

http://code.nethna.de/vEMan/about.html

Also, ESX(i) >= v5 has a *web client*